# How to interpret pseudocode time complexity?

Tags: algorithms

I am new to working with big-O, big-theta computation and wondering how I would find the tight bound of pseudocode like this?

The two loops iterate from $i/j$ to n so I understand that to be $\Theta(n)$, but how do I go about evaluating the inner loop and how does that affect the algorithm as a whole? I can't find any examples using pseudocode online so would appreciate some clarification.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @cpiegore The second paragraph of the post is explains what the asker understands about the problem and what the asker has tried so far, which is precisely the "context" that you're asking for.

Comment: @cpiegore not asking for an answer - just some clarification on the nested while loop - I know the first while and for loop are theta(n) but can't figure out what the time complexity of the second one is and would appreciate some guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building the array $A$ occurs in a single for loop and clearly takes $n$ steps.

The outer for loop runs $n$ times, with $j = 1,2,\dots,n$. The internal while loop is a bit trickier. If you trace through the code for small values of $n$ (e.g. $n = 4,5,6$), you find that the following pattern emerges:

- When $j = 1$, the while loop runs $n$ times, with $i = 1,2,\dots,n$.
- When $j = 2$, the while loops runs $1+\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$ times, with $i = 1,3,\dots,1+2\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor$
- When $j = 3$, the while loops runs $1+\lfloor (n-1)/3\rfloor$ times, with $i = 1,4,\dots,1+3\lfloor (n-1)/3\rfloor$
- For each $j$, the while loop runs $1+\lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor$ times, with $i = 1,1+j,\dots,1+j\lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor$.

Thus, the full runtime of the nested loop will be
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n (1+\lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor) = n + (1+\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor) + \cdots + (1+\lfloor (n-1)/n\rfloor).
$$
We can get an easier bound to work with on this sum as follows. Note that
$$
\frac {n}{j} - 2\leq \frac{n-1}{j} - 1\leq \lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor\leq \frac{n-1}{j} \leq \frac nj
$$
With that, we have the lower bound
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \left(1 + \frac {n}{j} - 2\right) = \left(n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1j  \right) - n
$$
and the upper bound
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(1 + \frac nj\right) = \left(n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1j\right) + n.
$$
The trick here is to get a handle on $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1j$. One way to do this is to use calculus: it turns out that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1j$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\int_1^n \frac 1x \,dx = \ln(n) = \Theta(\log(n))$, so that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1j = \Theta(\log(n))$. Thus, noting that $n = o(n\log(n))$, our bounds on the complexity $C(n)$ become
$$
\Theta(n \log(n) - n) = \Theta(n\log(n)) \leq C(n) \leq \Theta(n \log(n)) = \Theta(n \log(n) + n).
$$
Thus, the overall complexity of the nested loop is $\Theta(n \log(n))$. With that, the complexity of the overall algorithm is
$$
n + \Theta(n \log(n)) = \Theta(n \log(n)).
$$

Comment: Thank you. This pointed me in the right direction and made me realize some gaps in my math knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop takes time depending on $j$. Figure out how much. Then sum up that time for $j = 1$ to $n$.